# django API how to get parameter include special Characters

Tags: python, django, rest, api, parameters

hello now i make django api for searching mysql DB
but i will send parameter like this

```
%20%20%20chinkyu5211
```

it cognize chinkyu5211 except special characters

```
chinkyu5211
```

so if someone know that way to cognize %20%20%20chinkyu5211 all sentences plz teach me..

```
class SearchView(APIView):

def get(self, request):
    data_list=[]
    #es = Elasticsearch()

    # 검색어
    search_word = request.query_params.get('search')
    print(search_word)
```

this is my views code and if i printed search_word i got the result chinkyu5211 as i said before

i hope that the problem will be solved.. thanks you

Comment: It does already that, `%20` is decoded to a space. Since a URL uses percent-encoding.

Comment: no actually %20%20%20chinkyu5211 is saved in mysql

Comment: the api need to check DB and if they exists it will get the all data result and spread on the web so i need to get all sentence included special character!